# how i do when ihave this issue JSP Problem: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error Status when handling action?

Tags: java, jsp

I have searched the forums a lot for a solution to my problem but so far nothing. So I need your help!

Currently I am taking the Java EE course: "Develop websites with Java EE" on openclassrooms and arrived on JDBC I am blocked.

The principle consists of reading data in the database from the Java code and displaying them at the level of the JSP. But the display poses a problem at the JSP level. Thank you for your help! Here is my code for the JSP.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>titre</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bienvenue dans mon site</h1>
         
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="utilisateur" items="${ utilisateurs }" >
                <li><c:out value="${ utilisateurs.prenom }" /><c:out value="${ utilisateurs.nom }" /></li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
     
    </body>
</html>


import java.io.IOException;
 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 
import sn.mballo.bdd.Personnes;
 
@WebServlet("/bonjour")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    public Test() {
        super();
 
    }
 
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        Personnes tablePersonnes = new Personnes();
 
        request.setAttribute("utilisateurs", tablePersonnes.recupererUtilisateurs());
 
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/bonjour.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        doGet(request, response);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Check the stacktrace to find the error, so you know what needs to be fixed. If the stacktrace is not on the 500 error page, it should be in the log file.

Comment: Please share your console log! 500 is more likely because of a backend problem not JSP

Comment: This is wrong; ${ utilisateurs.prenom }   It should be  ${ utilisateur.prenom } and  ${ utilisateurs.nom }  should be  ${ utilisateur.nom }    Also the  <c:out>  is not necessary. EL can be used  in templete text.